# Spatial Lag Model and Heteroscedasticity

Tags: r, heteroscedasticity, spatial

I am using Spatial Lag Models with the form *y<sub>i</sub> = ρWy<sub>i</sub> + βX<sub>i</sub> + ε<sub>i</sub>*, and am estimating these in R using `spdep::lagsarlm`. However, Breusch-Pagan-Tests using `spdep::bptest.sarlm` indicate the presence of heteroscedasticity.

Therefore my question is, whether the asymptotic standard errors of the coefficients are robust against heteroscedasticity? As it is stated in the `spdep` manual (p. 87f.), `spdep::lagsarlm` uses Generalized Least Squares, which should be already consistent under heteroscedasticity, right?

But why is it stated in the `spdep` manual for `spdep::bptest.sarlm`(p. 17) then:

> It is also technically possible to make heteroskedasticity corrections
>   to standard error estimates by using the “lm.target” component of
>   sarlm objects - using functions in the lmtest and sandwich packages.

And if there are indeed corrections for standard errors required, how can I do this in the `spdep` package?